# Netflix Zuul annotation causes spring boot app fails to start

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

spring-boot-starter-parent uses 1.5.9

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Application :

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan({"com.bmc.common.portal","com.bmc.common.portal.controllers","com.bmc.dem", "com.bmc.costportal.controllers", "com.bmc.cost.portal"})
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class PortalApplication {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

       return (container -> {
            ErrorPage error400Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"/error/400.html");
            ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"/error/401.html");
            ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"/error/404.html");
            ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error/500.html");
            container.addErrorPages(error400Page, error401Page,error404Page, error500Page); });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error :

> [12 Sep 2018 20:36:26,702] [ERROR]
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Class;)V
>           at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>           atorg.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `spring-boot-starter-parent` from the 1.x branch with `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` from the 2.x branch.  2.x is not compatible with 1.x.  Try upgrading to a `spring-boot-starter-parent` from the 2.x branch or downgrading `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` to 1.x

Comment: I cannot use the Spring boot 2.x or above , as we share the session with different microservices and those service use spring boot 1.5.9

Comment: Then use the older zuul package.

Comment: Zuul 1.4.0 release fixed this, but causes another defect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343355/enabling-zuul-causes-instancealready-exists-exception